# How to pad a string with spaces in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a Ruby function that can pad a string?

Original `[477, 4770]`

Expected `["477  ", "4770 "]`

Comment: Can you provide an example code otherwise it's not really clear what you want?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should use [`String#ljust`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-ljust) from Ruby standard library:

```
arr = [477, 4770]
strings = arr.map { |number| number.to_s.ljust(5) }
# => ["477  ", "4770 "]
```

Comment: Obviously use `rjust(5)` to add padding spaces to the left side of the string (at the risk of stating the obvious!) - https://apidock.com/ruby/String/rjust

Answer (score 12):

You need the method [String#ljust](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-ljust). Here is an example:

```
t = 123
s = t.to_s.ljust(5, ' ')
```

Please note that `' '` is the default padding symbol. I only added it for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [477, 4770]

arr.collect {|num| num.to_s.ljust(5)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use printf formatting from [Kernel](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-format) as well :

```
arr = [477, 4770]
arr.map { |i| "%-5d" % i }
```